# How to do a SUM + TOP + obtain values from another table in the same query?

Tags: sql, sum

[image]

Given this structure, I want to obtain the top most sold IdProducto, their NomProducto (name from Productos table), according to the SUM of kilos sold in LineaVenta (which I also want to display)
I've tried several instructions, none of them worked as I want:

I get everything but NomProducto with this one:

```
SELECT TOP 5 IdProducto, SUM(Kilos) 
FROM LineaVenta 
GROUP BY  IdProducto 
ORDER BY SUM (Kilos) DESC
```

This one just wont work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 LineaVenta.IdProducto, SUM(LineaVenta.Kilos), Productos.NomProducto
FROM LineaVenta, Productos
GROUP BY  LineaVenta.IdProducto
ORDER BY SUM (LineaVenta.Kilos) DESC
```

Comment: What db server are you using?

Comment: @davejal Doesn't matter that much, could be done with ANSI SQL which fits most dbms

Comment: @sagi - OP has used `TOP` keyword to restrict the result set, where TOP is not a ANSI SQL keyword so I guess OP need's to clarify the `RDBMS`

Comment: Hi VR46, I'm using visual studio and an ADO.NET dataset

Comment: @ArturAlvaro - Those are not `RDBMS`. Here is few example's of RDBMS  `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `Mysql`, `DB2`, `Postgres`, etc..

Comment: @MotoGP sorry, I'm not sure how to know that

Answer (score 2):

You just need a proper `JOIN`.  Simple rule:  *NEVER* use a comma in a `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 5 p.IdProducto, p.NomProducto, SUM(v.Kilos) 
FROM LineaVenta v JOIN
     Productos p
     ON v.IdProducto = p.IdProducto
GROUP BY p.IdProducto, p.NomProducto
ORDER BY SUM(v.Kilos) DESC;
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to add NomProducto to the answer

Comment: Thanks sagi, but there's some kind of error for vb's says there's a problem in the query. I've spotted the l prefix for Kilos should be v wouldn't it? but still not working :/

Comment: @ArturAlvaro - What do you mean by not working. Are you getting any error

Comment: Yes @ArturAlvaro it should be v

Comment: I don't get any exception, but a warning. When I generate the query in the LineaVentaDataTable it says "The assistant detected the following problems: Select query generated; can't analize the query's text" and when I try to fill the datagridview where I want to display the result it doesn't show anything

Comment: @ArturAlvaro . . . With the right table alias, there is nothing obviously wrong with the query.